# Reset my network settings on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, dns

*Please read before marking this as a duplicate!*

I have searched here and also on other places but I can't seem to get a solution that actually works. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop. I have a very unreliable broadband internet at home that occasionally drops (for about a second or two) for no reason what so ever. I have tried switching routers. I have also tried using LAN cable. The problem is from my ISP. As a person living in a 3rd world country, there isn't anything I can do about that.

But the real problem is here. Whenever the internet drops out and comes back on, my computer has a difficult time picking it up. Other devices on the network aren't affected at all. My phone, and my other Windows laptop continue working fine. It's like they aren't even affected by the 2 second internet drop. But my Ubuntu machine just can not get access to the internet instantly. I have to disconnect and reconnect multiple times before it starts working again. Now this isn't a big deal unless I'm doing something that is "realtime". But when streaming and playing games, its really a huge annoyance. Particularly in Steam, when the connection drops, it switches to **NO INTERNET** (offline mode) and it just stays there for eternity.

I don't know if its related but I have Valet Linux installed (big mistake). The thing is, I can't uninstall Valet Linux because if I do, the computer can never connect to the internet. Simple as that. From my understanding, Valet Linux handles all the DNS stuff. So when I install it, it just leaves everything with out anyone to handle it.

All I want to do is reset my network settings to factory settings (like a fresh Ubuntu install). I can't do a clean install at the moment because of too much prep needed (drivers that were a pain to setup and a lot of other configurations). Can anyone walk me through the process of resetting my network configuration to factory settings.

Thank you in advance,
Tamrat

**EDIT**

```
$ dkms status
bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 4.15.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 4.15.0-43-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 390.77, 4.15.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 390.77, 4.15.0-43-generic, x86_64: installed
virtualbox, 5.2.18, 4.15.0-43-generic, x86_64: installed

$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for tamrat: 
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlp8s0
       version: 03
       serial: 10:08:b1:e4:1a:31
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=192.168.0.108 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 memory:d1600000-d1607fff memory:d1400000-d15fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: enp9s0
       version: 10
       serial: f0:76:1c:5b:d9:93
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:d1804000-d1804fff memory:d1800000-d1803fff
```

Comment: It sounds like you normally connect via a wireless connection, yes? If so, disconnecting the wireless connection, and using a hard-wired ethernet cable, you have the same results, yes? Edit your question to show me `dkms status` and `sudo lshw -C network`.